# JNativehook not capturing passwords

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface, keylogger

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I'm learning Java and I'm experimenting with JNI. One thing I'm now doing is trying to make a keylogger. I've got it to write the keystrokes to a file, et cetera, but it's not capturing password keystrokes. My guess is that JNativehook disabled it intentionally.

So, I went looking into the source code but found nothing. I'm mainly looking for a solution on OS X, as that's all I need.

If anyone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the result of a security feature on OS X and is part of the way JNativeHook was designed to function.  Most systems do not enforce this kind of policy, however, Apple has really lead the way on input security via their accessibility API.  If you want to get password data on OS X, you will need to create something at the kernel level and it will require some kind of privilege escalation to at least install.

Comment: I know I shouldn't say something like "thanks", but I still want to thank you for your comment.